# How To stop git accessing my changes made in django project in vscode

Tags: django, github, git-bash

I had pushed my django project into github from vscode,later i deactivated my virtual environment,but even after deactivating if i try to make any changes in my project it is asking me to apply local changes to git,how to prevent it?[Please Help me To Solve this Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X7aw8.png)

i deactivated the virtual environment and made changes on my project,but it is still asking me to apply those changes to git.I dont want this changes to be applied to github,how to prevent it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have confused yourself with Git, Github and Virtualenv

Virtualenv is just a tool to manage your different python related environments you may need to create, run and work on different python projects which may use different versions of the same package in a single computer.

Git is a tool to version control your source code, so that you can easily go back to a version from an earlier point

Github is an online web application to which you can push your code using git, so that your code now is not only version controlled in your local computer but is also available on a cloud environment where you can share and collaborate with others.

Whenever you do any updates in your code, you will need to add those files and commit them to git if you want them to be version controlled.

Comment: Did you get this solved?

Answer (score 0):

There is a button like "Don't add to git" or something like this in VSCode which you can use.
Plus, you can use a ".gitignore" file where you can store file names that you don't want git to track them.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).